# Some custom fields automatically created when creating a new salesforce development instance

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects

When I created a new SFDC instance, In Account object setup i saw some custom fields like SLAExpirationDate_*c ,NumberofLocations*_c (not created by any user).
Same case for contact and other standard objects.
Can anyone tell me why these fields are automatically created?

Answer (score 4):

Those customizations are just intended to demonstrate declarative customizations of a Salesforce org. Just the same way `Start_Here` Tab, Page and Apex classes are to demonstrate coding customizations.

If you take umbrage to these existing customizations, I can give you an `ant` target to purge them out:

```
<target name="purge" description="Purges an organization of most customizations and components">
    <!-- Clean up any previous purge -->
    <delete dir="purge" />
    <mkdir dir="purge" />

    <!-- Prepare a wildcard package definition with as many metadata types as possible -->
    <echo file="purge/package.xml"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <types><members>*</members><name>AccountCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>AccountOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>AccountSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>AnalyticSnapshot</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ApexClass</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ApexComponent</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ApexPage</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ApexTrigger</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ApexTriggerCoupling</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>AuthProvider</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>BusinessProcess</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CallCenter</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CampaignCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CampaignOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CampaignSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CaseCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CaseOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CaseSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CompactLayout</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ConnectedApp</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ContactCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ContactOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ContactSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomApplication</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomApplicationComponent</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomField</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomLabel</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomLabels</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObject</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObjectCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObjectOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObjectSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObjectTranslation</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomPageWebLink</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>CustomTab</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Dashboard</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>DataCategoryGroup</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Document</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>EmailTemplate</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>FieldSet</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>FlexiPage</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Flow</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Group</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>LeadCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>LeadOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>LeadSharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Letterhead</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ListView</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>NamedFilter</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>OpportunityCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>OpportunityOwnerSharingRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>OpportunitySharingRules</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>RecordType</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>RemoteSiteSetting</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Report</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ReportType</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>SamlSsoConfig</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Scontrol</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>SharingReason</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>StaticResource</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>ValidationRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WebLink</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>Workflow</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowAlert</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowApex</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowChatterPost</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowKnowledgePublish</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowOutboundMessage</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowQuickCreate</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowRule</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowSend</name></types>
            <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowTask</name></types>
            <version>29.0</version>
        </Package>
    ]]></echo>

    <!--
     ! These metadata types are either unpackageable, or tricky because
     ! they are coupled to profiles (app) or users (permissionsets):
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>ApprovalProcess</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>AssignmentRule</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>AssignmentRules</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>AutoResponseRule</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>AutoResponseRules</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Community</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>CustomSite</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>EscalationRule</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>EscalationRules</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>HomePageComponent</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>HomePageLayout</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>InstalledPackage</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Layout</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>PermissionSet</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Profile</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Queue</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>QuickAction</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Role</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>Settings</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>SynonymDictionary</name></types>
     ! <types><members>*</members><name>WorkflowActionFlow</name></types>
     !-->

    <!-- Retrieve the wildcard package definition -->
    <sf:retrieve
    username="${sf.username}"
    password="${sf.password}"
    serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
    retrieveTarget="purge"
    unpackaged="purge/package.xml"
    pollWaitMillis="1000" />

    <!--
     ! These components retrieve ok, but attempting to deploy them throws:
     ! "Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first"
     ! We delete them so they don't make their way into destructiveChanges.xml
     !-->
    <delete file="purge/workflows/Question.workflow" />
    <delete file="purge/workflows/Reply.workflow" />
    <delete file="purge/workflows/SocialPersona.workflow" />
    <delete file="purge/workflows/SocialPost.workflow" />

    <!-- Name the package definition -->
    <replace file="purge/package.xml">
        <replacetoken><![CDATA[</version>]]></replacetoken>
        <replacevalue><![CDATA[</version><fullName>Purge</fullName>]]></replacevalue>
    </replace>

    <!-- Re-deploy the now-named wildcard package definition -->
    <sf:deploy
    username="${sf.username}"
    password="${sf.password}"
    serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
    deployRoot="purge"
    purgeOnDelete="true"
    pollWaitMillis="1000" />

    <!-- Retrieve by name, giving us an explicit package definition -->
    <sf:retrieve
    username="${sf.username}"
    password="${sf.password}"
    serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
    retrieveTarget="purge"
    packageNames="Purge"
    pollWaitMillis="1000" />

    <!--
     ! Trash local components: we only needed them to get an explicit package definition.
     ! Now we turn the explicit package definition into explicit destructive changes, and
     ! blank out the package definition.
     !-->
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" dir="purge" includes="**/*" excludes="*.xml" />
    <copy file="purge/package.xml" tofile="purge/destructiveChanges.xml" />
    <echo file="purge/package.xml"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <version>29.0</version>
        </Package>
    ]]></echo>

    <!-- Perform explicit deploy over the top of the org which should delete all components -->
    <sf:deploy
    username="${sf.username}"
    password="${sf.password}"
    serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
    deployRoot="purge"
    purgeOnDelete="true"
    pollWaitMillis="1000" />

    <!-- Tidy up after ourselves -->
    <delete dir="purge" />
</target>
```